# Fastest way to clamp an integer to the range 0-255

Tags: c++, performance, image, bitwise, assembly

I'm working on some image processing code that can generate pixel values outside of the normal range of 0 to 255, and I'd like to clamp them back into the valid range. I know that there are saturating SIMD instructions that make this a moot point, but I'm trying to stay within standard C++ code for the moment.

The fastest I've been able to do on my Athlon II is the following:

```
inline
BYTE Clamp(int n)
{
    n &= -(n >= 0);
    return n | ((255 - n) >> 31);
}
```

This compiles down into the following assembly with MSVC 6.0:

```
setns dl
neg   edx
and   eax, edx
mov   edx, 255
sub   edx, eax
sar   edx, 31
or    dl, al
```

Is there any improvement possible?

Comment: Does it have to be signed?

Comment: why AND'ing with 0xFF is not an option?

Comment: @Pubby, yes the values can be less than 0 or greater than 255.

Comment: @littleadv, the idea is that values outside the range take on the closest value within the range. I.e. you want -1 to become 0, and ANDing will not accomplish that.

Comment: OK, got it:) I'm not familiar with the term "clamping" for that:)

Comment: The funny thing is that when I loop the function 900000000 times over a set of 3 different inputs (-1, 256, 20), I only get a 300ms as opposed to using if statements to do the range checking/altering. It'd be interesting to see if you can get it faster though.

Comment: Is it any faster to check if the high byte (0xff00) is non-zero then set to 255?

Comment: It may be worth it to test if it's in range if that is the most likely case, taking less time for a valid value and a little more time for out of range numbers.

Comment: @jswolf19, that's a good thought - I think over 99% of my data will be within range. Unfortunately with modern processors it's faster to treat everything the same than it is to take different paths for different conditions.

Comment: I can think of way to average only 1.0 instructions/`int` on x86 and (0.5 instructions/`int` on x64) just to check if the value is in range. So you could run this over a block size (unrolled and everything) and for the rare chance that you do have an out-of-range value, you pay the misprediction penalty + fix up code...

Comment: @Mystical, right now it's inline with the code that generates the values. I don't think I'd gain anything by saving the intermediate values and making a second pass.

Comment: VC6?  Really?  Aren't newer compilers cleverer with optimisations and faster?

Comment: @AshleysBrain, I also have VS 2010 Express and I should probably try it there too for completeness. I'm too dependent on MFC to make it my compiler of choice.

Comment: This seems like a parallelizable task; I wonder if splitting a large image into n chunks could help some.

Comment: @Leonid, it's very parallelizable but you'd still want each subtask to run as fast as it can.

Comment: In a sad way, it's good to see that in 2011, somebody was (is?) still using MSVC6 for some things. I'm in the same, sad, situation. :-}

Comment: You should use `sizeof(int)`, which is not necessarily 32.

Comment: @200_success, actually it would be `(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT)-1`. You're correct of course, but I'm unlikely to use this code on any platform where an `int` isn't 32 bits.

Comment: I independently arrived at an answer similar to what @Mysticial posted: `(n &= (~n >> 31)) | (0xFF - n) >> 31`, a one-liner which works great and is a bit sleeker. I was going to post a new answer because I had additional remarks but don't yet have enough reputation to answer a protected question. In short, my comments were about testing the input cases carefully, especially in-and-around the range `0x80000000`-`0x800000FF` (which should all result in `0`). Mixing bitwise with arithmetic operations can be tricky, causing bugs which aren't noticed because they only show up near `0x80000000`.

Comment: C++17 has [`std::clamp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp), which seems well optimized by GCC, but the output of Clang is suboptimal, see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hPG636).

Comment: @MarkRansom Done!

Comment: @200_success, I'd be quite interested to learn of a platform where `sizeof (int)` *is* as large as 32...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try

```
 int x=n>255?255:n;
 ... x<0?0:x ...
```

I'd expect this to produce something like:

```
 mov     ebx, 255
 mov     eax, n
 cmp     eax, ebx
 cmovg   eax, ebx ; conditional mov instruction
 test    eax, eax
 mov     ebx, 0
 cmovl   eax, ebx
```

If you are using MSVC SIX, you may not get the conditional move instruction. Try switching to a modern version of visual studio.

Comment: I do have MSVC 2010 express, so I could try it there. Unfortunately I have two conditions to test for - less than 0, and greater than 255.

Comment: If this is a pixel value, why are you working with signed values?

Comment: @MarkRansom: the casting to unsigned takes care of negative values

Comment: @6502, casting -1 to unsigned will generate a large positive value which will be converted to 255. I'd rather it convert to 0.

Comment: @MarkRansom: you are 100% right. I'll blame for this being on fever in a saturday morning :-)

Comment: @IraBaxter, the algorithm produces values outside the range of 0 to 255 so an integer is necessary to to capture the full range, but of course the output must be constrained after the fact. This isn't uncommon in image processing.

Comment: @6502: Mark wanted negative numbers to produce zero.

Comment: Ira, you must have changed this code since I left my first comments. I finally got around to trying VS 2010, and this becomes the fastest method. It still doesn't use the conditional move instruction, but it does make a very interesting optimization.

Comment: I did, but StackOverflow migrated the question, and lost the edit times, so you couldn't see it.  I see your revised answer with the short (predicted) branch; the CMOV I think is still the fastest way to do this because there is no branch ever.  If MS won't generate it directly, you can always make a bit of assembler code. Thanks for noticing the changes, and for the brownie point.

Comment: I'm glad that we're at the point where the most straightforward code is also the fastest in this situation.

Comment: Guys, how about this `x = 255 ^ ((n ^ 255) & -(n < 255));`? It will give you minimum of both. See [this](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax). Would this be fastest?

Comment: Why is this marked as answer? There is no cmovgt (it's cmovg, but sure) instruction and a conditional move with immediate value doesn't exist. What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, the idea sketch was OK.  Objections noted and answer revised.

Answer (score 33):

Here's my attempt:

```
unsigned char clamp(int n){
    int a = 255;
    a -= n;
    a >>= 31;
    a |= n;
    n >>= 31;
    n = ~n;
    n &= a;
    return n;
}
```

It compiles to 7 instructions - which is the same as your current version. So it may or may not be faster. I haven't timed it though. But I think these are all single-cycle instructions.

```
mov eax, 255
sub eax, ecx
sar eax, 31
or  al , cl
sar ecx, 31
not cl
and al , cl
```

Comment: I tried this out, and it slowed my overall benchmark time from 0.24 seconds to 0.31. Nice attempt though.

Comment: Awww... Oh well... I tried, not sure if I can do any better...

Comment: I just looked at the assembly and for some reason it would not inline your version - that probably accounts for the difference.

Comment: Ooh... you can try a macro? Or a compiler force inline?

Comment: I tried adding the `inline` keyword to the function, which I thought wouldn't make any difference - the compiler is supposed to know when it's worthwhile to inline without needing any hints. It brought the runtime from 0.31 to 0.23, which is a hair faster than mine. Congratulations!

Comment: How much of the run-time is actually spent doing the clamping? I'm kinda curious as to how much faster this version is - and I'm too lazy to knock up a benchmark right now. :-)

Comment: Replacing the function with `return n` changed the time from 0.24 seconds to 0.21, so your improvement is more significant than it appears at first glance. This might motivate me to do a better benchmark, but not tonight.

Answer (score 18):

Conclusion 2011-12-05:

I tried all of the suggestions again with VS 2010 Express. The generated code didn't change much, but the register assignments did which affected the overall results. A slight modification of the straightforward implementation suggested by Ira Baxter came up the winner.

```
inline
BYTE Clamp(int n)
{
    n = n>255 ? 255 : n;
    return n<0 ? 0 : n;
}

    cmp  ecx, 255
    jle  SHORT $LN8
    mov  ecx, 255
$LN8:
    test ecx, ecx
    sets bl
    dec  bl
    and  bl, cl
```

I learned a valuable lesson with this. I started with an assumption that bit-twiddling would beat anything that included a branch; I hadn't really tried any code that included an if statement or ternary operator. That was a mistake, as I hadn't counted on the power of the branch prediction built into a modern CPU. A ternary solution turned out to be the fastest, especially when the compiler substituted its own bit-twiddling code for one of the cases. The overall timing for this function within my benchmark algorithm went from 0.24 seconds to 0.19. This is very close to the 0.18 seconds that resulted when I removed the clamp entirely.

Comment: Did you try using unsigned compare to combine the check for less-than-zero with the check for >255?  (negative numbers are large unsigned numbers)  e.g. `cmp  ecx, 255 / jbe .good`, so in the case where clamping it not needed, it's a single  taken fused-compare-and-branch , then back to the rest of your code.  Or, make the no-clamping case the not-taken branch, and put the clamping off with other cold code, followed by a jump back.  There are some good answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071144/x86-assembly-optimization-of-simple-code, (where there's a variable upper-bound).

Comment: You can do better than that code.  See my answer on the SO question I linked.  `cmp ecx, 255 / jbe .no_clamp / mov cl, 255 / mov bl, 0 / cmovg bl, cl`  If you can spare a register to hold a zero constant, or want to cmov from a memory constant for the rare case when clamping is needed, you can pull the `mov bl, 0` out.  Emulating cmov with `setcc/dec/and` isn't worth it, even though `cmov` is a 2-uop instruction on Intel.

Comment: @PeterCordes this question is about C/C++ code, not assembly. The assembly is only there to help understand why one source construct might be faster than another, and it's all compiler generated.

Answer (score 8):

I'd be curious how a simple branched solution would perform?

```
inline char Clamp(int n)
{
    if(n < 0)
        return 0;
    else if(n > 255)
        return 255;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: +1. Some benchmarks are in order. This could very well take advantage of the superscalar speculative branch execution of modern CPUs, and be quite fast indeed.

Comment: This is nearly the same as Jonathan Leffler's Clamp_2, which performed much better than I expected. I wonder if fiddling with the order makes a difference? I'll have to let you know later.

Comment: I'm curious to see how `return std::min(std::max(0, n), 255);` will fair against the competition.

Comment: It's quite good:
https://godbolt.org/z/Ni_obb

Similar to Mark Ransom's:
https://godbolt.org/z/Z4rYdP

The one in this answer is jumpy so I doubt it would win:
https://godbolt.org/z/meEuH1

Answer (score 7):

Using GCC/LLVM on MacOS X, and 64-bit compilation, and generating assembler with:

```
gcc -S -Os clamp.c
```

where `clamp.c` contains:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

BYTE Clamp_1(int n)
{
    n &= -(n >= 0);
    return n | ((255 - n) >> 31);
}

BYTE Clamp_2(int n)
{
    if (n > 255)
        n = 255;
    else if (n < 0)
        n = 0;
    return n;
}
```

The assembler for the two functions (with prologue and epilogue) is:

```
    .section        __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _Clamp_1
_Clamp_1:
Leh_func_begin1:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    movl    %edi, %eax
    shrl    $31, %eax
    xorl    $1, %eax
    negl    %eax
    andl    %edi, %eax
    movl    $255, %ecx
    subl    %eax, %ecx
    sarl    $31, %ecx
    orl     %eax, %ecx
    movzbl  %cl, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end1:

    .globl  _Clamp_2
_Clamp_2:
Leh_func_begin2:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp2:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp3:
    cmpl    $256, %edi
    jl      LBB2_2
    movl    $255, %edi
    jmp     LBB2_4
LBB2_2:
    testl   %edi, %edi
    jns     LBB2_4
    xorl    %edi, %edi
LBB2_4:
    movzbl  %dil, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end2:
```

The `pushq`, `popq` and `ret` are the function call overhead.  Your code (`Clamp_1()`) assembles to 11 instructions; mine to 9 (but there are two jumps in mine, which might wreak havoc on pipelined execution).  Neither approaches the 7 instructions in your optimized version.

Interestingly, though, when I use GCC 4.6.1 on the same code, the assembler output is:

```
    .text
    .globl _Clamp_1
_Clamp_1:
LFB0:
    movl    %edi, %eax
    movl    $255, %edx
    notl    %eax
    sarl    $31, %eax
    andl    %edi, %eax
    subl    %eax, %edx
    sarl    $31, %edx
    orl     %edx, %eax
    ret
LFE0:
    .globl _Clamp_2
_Clamp_2:
LFB1:
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    testl   %edi, %edi
    movl    $255, %eax
    cmovns  %edi, %edx
    cmpl    $255, %edx
    cmovle  %edx, %eax
    ret
LFE1:
```

Now I see 8 instructions in `Clamp_1` and 6 in `Clamp_2` apart from the `ret`.

---

Further experimentation shows that there is a difference in the output between `gcc -Os -S clamp.c` and `gcc -S -Os clamp.c`; the former generates the optimized (smaller) outputs; the latter generates the more verbose output.

Comment: Strangely it never occurred to me to test my code against the straightforward implementation you presented here. I tried it and the time went from 0.24 seconds to 0.29, so no improvement there. Obviously though the compiler and surrounding code can make a huge difference. Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: I just tried the same test but including the `inline` keyword and it brought the time down to 0.23 seconds. I must remember to include it in every test from now on.

Comment: I had been trying to avoid branches on the theory that they took an an inordinate amount of time, but obviously branch prediction is more advanced than I had assumed. Thanks for rattling my assumptions!

Comment: You might get even better speed with a single test (`if(n & 0xFFFFFF00 != 0)`) to look for out of range and let the in-range values only take the and, test and jump...

Answer (score 5):

C++17 introduces [`std::clamp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp), so your function can be implemented as follows:

```
#include <algorithm>

inline BYTE Clamp(int n) {
    return std::clamp(n, 0, 255);
}
```

Which seems well optimized by [GCC (version 10.2)](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:5),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%0Aunsigned+char+clamp(int+n)+%7B%0A++++return+std::clamp(n,+0,+255)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), using only comparison and conditional move instructions as seen in many of the older answers:

```
clamp(int):
        cmp     edi, 255
        mov     eax, 255
        mov     edx, 0
        cmovle  eax, edi
        test    eax, eax
        cmovs   eax, edx
        ret
```

However, at the time of writing, the assembler output of [Clang (version 10.0.0)](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:5),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%0Aunsigned+char+clamp(int+n)+%7B%0A++++return+std::clamp(n,+0,+255)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1000,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+10.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) and [ICC (version 19.0.1)](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:5),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%0Aunsigned+char+clamp(int+n)+%7B%0A++++return+std::clamp(n,+0,+255)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:icc191,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+icc+19.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) are suboptimal. [MSVC (version 19.24)](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:16,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:16,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:16,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:16,startLineNumber:3),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%0Aunsigned+char+clamp(int+n)+%7B%0A++++return+std::clamp(n,+0,+255)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:54.3875968992248,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_24_x64,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27/O2+/std:c%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x64+msvc+v19.24+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:45.61240310077518,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) is almost optimal but adds one branch instruction.

Comment: Silly compilers; we can take advantage of the unsigned compare trick to use the same `cmp` result twice for both `cmovae` and `cmovge`, as shown in this answer: [x86 assembly - optimization of clamping rax to \[ 0 .. limit )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65394440).  GCC's version is especially bad, putting `test` on the critical path by testing the first `cmov`'s output instead of the original EDI input.  And yeah, clang 10 and 11 are insane, using memory and selecting one of 3 addresses to load from.  Clang 9 does close to what GCC does.

Comment: No, `clamp<unsigned>` treats negative `n` as high unsigned numbers, clamping them to 255 not 0.  That's not what the OP wants for this question; it's signed clamping to 0..255.  That does need 2 CMOV instructions for the 2 possible clamp values.

Answer (score 3):

The result may depend a bit upon whether the pixel data is predictably more often in-range than out of range.  This might be quicker in the former case:

```
int clamp(int n)
{
    if ((unsigned) n <= 255) {
        return n;
    }
    return (n < 0) ? 0 : 255;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your < 0 clamp and modifying the > 255 one, how does this stack up?

```
inline 
BYTE Clamp(int n)
{
  n &= -(n >= 0);
  return n | ~-!(n & -256);
}
```

The disassembly of the second line (below) on my machine has one extra instruction, but no (expensive) shifts.

```
mov  eax, ecx
and  eax, -256
neg  eax
sbb  eax, eax
or   eax, ecx
```

Comment: About the same as mine, 0.24 seconds overall including a lot of other stuff going on. I don't think shifts have been expensive since the 386 days, the barrel shifter makes any shift count possible within a single clock cycle.

Comment: I guess you can tell how long I've been doing x86 assembly. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned char clamp(int n) {
    return (-(n >= 0) & n) | -(n >= 255);
}
```

You can optimize this if you can optimize -(a >= b)

Answer (score 1):

This may be a worthwhile function, despite the existence of `std::clamp`, since it's likely that the 0-255 range is open to optimisations that don't apply to the general function (e.g. more SIMD-friendly code).  I'd give it a different, more specific name, though.

---

The hardcoded 31-bit shift is only appropriate if `int` happens to be 32 bits wide.  Instead of embedding that assumption, it would be better to make it explicit in the function signature (and that also allows us to overload the function for other integer types):

```
#include <cstdint>
inline BYTE clamp_pixel(std::int32_t n);
```

As an added bonus, it will no longer compile on platforms that don't have a 32-bit integer type, alerting us to the need to modify this function.

---

Although it's declared elsewhere, the typename `BYTE` is a poor choice, especially for an arithmetic type, given that `std::byte` is not an arithmetic type.  You probably want `std::uint_fast8_t` there, I think.

Comment: The definition of `BYTE` came from Microsoft, and it's either a macro or a typedef for `unsigned char`.  Your change to the parameter type is a good idea though.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise it was imposed by your platform (not being a Microsoft user myself).  Sorry to accuse you of that!

Comment: It wasn't *imposed* so much as it became a habit.  Microsoft created their types before the equivalents were available in the standard.  At the time I asked the question I wasn't as familiar with the `std` types as I am today.

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
x &= 255
```

It is very efficient and has no effect on values in the normal range. I would like to know what proportion of your results need clamping. If a simple and won't do the trick, try this:

```
x &= (~x) >> 8
```

Comment: This was already suggested in the comments. Unfortunately it doesn't do the right thing with values outside the normal range - I want values less than 0 to become 0 and values greater than 255 to become 255. You're right about it being efficient though.